# javascript - split string by specifying starting and ending characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string `(100*##G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of new installs@@-##G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of uninstalls@@`

I want to split the string in such a way that it returns the following result (i.e it matches all characters that starts with `##` and ends with `@@` and splits the string with matched characters)

```
["(100*", "G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of new installs", '-', 'G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of uninstalls'
```

Comment: The initial string will have hyphen between those 2 characters. So when splitting the string with this specified characters, it needs to give hyphen in ouput

Comment: Sounds a lot like you just want to split on `##` or `@@`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) passing a regex.

```js
var str = "(100*##G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of new installs@@-##G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of uninstalls@@";

var re = /##(.*?)@@/;

var result = str.split(re);
console.log(result);
```

When you use [Capturing parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Capturing_parentheses) in the regex, the captured text is also returned in the array.

Note that this will have an ending `""` entry, because your string ends with `@@`. If you don't want that, just remove it.

---

- If you always assume a well-formed string, the following regex yields the same result:

  ```
  /##|@@/
  ```

  <sup>*Commented by [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)</sup>
- If you expect newlines in between `##` and `@@`, change the expression to:

  ```
  /##([\s\S]*?)@@/
  ```
- If you need it to perform better, specially failing faster with longer strings:

  ```
  /##([^@]*(?:@[^@]+)*)@@/
  ```

  <sup>*[Benchmark](https://jsfiddle.net/wp77sas2/)</sup>

Comment: Seems like the same result you get with `/##|@@/`, which would be simpler. (Assuming a well-formed string.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Except when you have unclosed structures, e.g. `aaa##zzz`. So it depends on what you expect in the input.

Comment: Heh, was just adding "...assuming a well-formed string." :-)

Comment: Haha... And I was adding the "...depends on what you expect..." :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can first split by `##`, then split each of the results by `@@`, and flatten the resulting array, like the following.

```
s.split('##').map(el => el.split('@@')).reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr))
```

Note that the last element of the resulting array will be empty string if you original string ends with `@@`, so you might need to remove it, depending on your use-case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
var s = '(100*##G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of new installs@@-##G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of uninstalls@@'

var arr = s.split(/(##.*?@@)/).filter(Boolean)

//=> ["(100*", "##G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of new installs@@", "-", "##G. Mobile Dashboard||Android App ( Practo.com )||# of uninstalls@@"]
```

- Use a capturing group to get split text in resulting array
- `filter(Boolean)` is needed to remove empty result from array